# New text not showing up

Tags: javascript, html

I made a Quotes generator website, Which uses an API. When I click Generate Quote it is just stuck on loading
How can I fix it?

```js
function randomQuote(){
    quoteBtn.classList.add("loading");
    quoteBtn.innerText = "Loading Quote...";
    fetch("http://api.quotable.io/random").then(response => response.json()).then(result => {
        quoteText.innerText = result.content;
        authorName.innerText = result.author;
        quoteBtn.classList.remove("loading");
        quoteBtn.innerText = "New Quote";
quoteBtn.addEventListener("click", randomQuote);
    });
}
```

Also I get this error which I do not know how to fix

```
index.js:12 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://mrquoter.netlify.app/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://api.quotable.io/random'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Also when I run it on my local server it runs fine, But I hosted it on netlify.app and it gives out an error

Comment: Try:`https://api.quotable.io/random` That's `https` You can't expect `https://mrquoter.netlify.app/` a secure protocol to connect to a non-secure protocol.

Comment: You are getting a http error, so your request fails the Promise returned from `fetch` is rejected. Catch the error and do something sensible with it, and fix the mixed content error to actually get the response back.

Answer (score 0):

You can not mix loading resources from **HTTP** sources when you have a **HTTPS** website because it alters the behavior of your HTTPS website (i.e. a secure website is not secure anymore) which opens up for new attack vectors on your HTTPS website as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content#mixed_active_content).

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a secure endpoint: `https://api.quotable.io/random`
2. Perhaps use [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) to make your code easier to parse.
3. Keep the button outside of the element you're updating.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const quote = document.querySelector('.quote');

const endpoint = 'https://api.quotable.io/random';

button.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

async function handleClick() {
  const response = await fetch(endpoint);
  const data = await response.json();
  quote.textContent = data.content;
}
```

```css
.quote { margin-top: 1em; }
```

```html
<button>New quote</button>
<div class="quote"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to change the query URL to
'https://api.quotable.io/random'
As your website uses HTTPs but you are calling the API with HTTP

> HTTPs is a secure version of HTTP

> You can find more about HTTP & HTTPs [Here](https://www.javatpoint.com/http-vs-https)